# what is the source of reciting ledovid boruch

Tags: minhag, tehilim-psalms, maariv, motzei-shabbos

What is the source for reciting ledovid boruch and lamnazeach at mozei shabbes before mairiv?

In the mishna berurah it is only cited as minhag but without a source.

Comment: Hi David, and welcome to Mi Yodeya. If you would add in where in the Mishna Brura it says that, that would be nice.

Comment: In (סימן רצג סײק א) lamnzaeach is cited directly: המנהג לזמר קדם מעריב המזמור אלוהים יחוננו ועוד מזמורים כנזכר בסידורים

Answer (score 2):

[Bais Ashkenaz](http://www.ashkenazhouse.org/minhagh.html) brings it as one of the Minhagei Ashkenaz.

> מוצאי שבת. לפני תפילת ערבית היו שרים מזמור קמ"ד בתהילים "לדוד ברוך
>   ה'", ואחריו מזמור ס"ז "למנצח בנגינות".

Comment: It is also a common minhag of the sefaradim to recite these chapters, so i am sure that the minhag is quite old and not exclusively an ashkenaizi minhag. Furthermore i would be interested to know if there is some rishon which cites this minhag and what the reason is why specifically these chapters where chosen.